# Multiple PHP version WITHOUT WAMP/XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, apache, server

:D

Impossible to find what I want by searching hours on google.

By any chance, does anyone know how to set up multiple PHP versions on a Windows install with Apache 2.4 on it and how to choose version on vhosts ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think you would have to look at a FastCGI configuration to be able to do that

Comment: Using your comment and the offered solution, I managed to configure it ! Thanks RiggsFolly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I figured out the problem !

In my Apache httpd.conf

```
 LoadModule fcgid_module /server/Apache-2.4/modules/mod_fcgid.so

<IfModule fcgid_module>
    FcgidInitialEnv PATH "C:/server/php-5.6-nts/php.ini;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;"
    FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:\Windows"
    FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:"
    FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:\Windows\Temp"
    FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:\Windows\Temp"
    FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:\WINDOWS"
    FcgidIOTimeout 1200
    FcgidConnectTimeout 1200
    FcgidBusyScanInterval 1200
    FcgidBusyTimeout 1200
    FcgidErrorScanInterval 1200
    FcgidIdleScanInterval 1200
    FcgidIdleTimeout 1200
    FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
    FcgidZombieScanInterval 1200
    # Location php.ini:
    FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:/server/php-5.6-nts"
    FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000

    <Files ~ "\.php$">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php
        FcgidWrapper "C:/server/php-5.6-nts/php-cgi.exe" .php
    </Files>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .phps
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
</IfModule>
```

Then in my vhost config :

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName xxx.xxx
  DocumentRoot "C:/www/xxx"
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php 
      FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "/server/php-5.2-nts" 
    <Directory "C:/www/xxx"> 
        AllowOverride All
            order allow,deny 
            allow from all 
            deny from none 
            Require all granted
        <Files ~ "\.php$"> 
            AddHandler fcgid-script .php 
            FcgidWrapper "/server/php-5.2-nts/php-cgi.exe" .php 
            Options +ExecCGI 
            order allow,deny 
            allow from all 
            deny from none 
            Require all granted
        </Files> 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I can declare whatever PHP version I want !

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to do that. You should use PHP as an Apache module, and in each vhost configuration, you can define which PHP version to use.

You can [find out more](http://gggeek.altervista.org/2007/07/21/running-multiple-php-versions-on-a-single-apache-install/) here or you could also check out [this site](https://www.dionysopoulos.me/233-apache-mysql-php-server-on-windows-with-multiple-simultaneous-php-versions.html) for a detailed answer.

Comment: only 1 php version can run as an apache module, the others must limit themselves to cgi. As it states in the first document you reference.

Comment: @3615_Internet You should not accept this answer as it states the completely wrong answer

Comment: @3615_Internet On top of that it is basically a link only answer and those are frowned upon in SO